# click event - I have 3 accordions and I want to know how to manage one event at a time using only one method

Tags: angular, typescript, events

This is my code. I have 3 lists of the same format but have different titles (test1, test2, test3). My problem is that every time I click test1 the boolean will turn to false which is correct but the problem.

```
Invalid test
case collapse   before click after click result  
test1           true         false       correct
test2           false        true        invalid - before click must be set to true
test3           true/false   true/false  invalid - the before and after result will be depended on 
                                                   the two test

Correct test 
case collapse   before click after click result  
test1           true         false       correct
test2           true         false       correct
test3           true         false       correct.
```

The only solution for this is to separate all methods using click1 click2 click3 but this is way too redundancy. if I have 15 accordions, therefore I have to create 15 clicks methods which are not appropriate.

```
 <li>
    <mat-accordion>
          <mat-expansion-panel [class.mat-expansion-panel]="false" hideToggle="true">
                <mat-expansion-panel-header (click)="isClick()">
                   <mat-panel-title>Test1</mat-panel-title>
                   <mat-icon [style.visibility]="!isCollapse ? 'visible': 'hidden'">close</mat-icon>
                </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto, quo?</p>
           </mat-expansion-panel>
     </mat-accordion>
```

Do you have any idea how to separate them using only one method? 
Is there like an evaluation that determines what element you are clicking?

Thanks.

Comment: are you talking about `isCollapse` variable ?

Comment: Yes. isCollapse is just boolean value.

Comment: I need to know if what element is clicking so that I can evaluated it on the component class.

because every time I click test1 - isCollapse - false then when I click test2 - it became true which is wrong and so on and so forth.

Comment: I need to check the element being click before I evaluate isCollapse. But do know how. without creating many variables. Because If I had 25 accordions then I have to create 25 isCollapse variable 1,2,3,4 which is not appropriate.

Comment: Since `isCollapse` is a single variable, it will reflect either in 1 accordion or in none. So you need a variable which is local to every accordion. Try wrapping your `mat-accordion` inside `ng-template`. In `ng-template` you can define a local variable and then you can pass that in your click method.